# php add years to the current date only once, if mysql table field is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, hidden-field, isnull, dateadd

I am creating an advertising website. The advertisements will be valid for two years, calculated from the customers’ first login date. For that purpose, I have 4 pages:

1. LOGIN page;
2. PROFILE page, after the customer login, where the customer can enter his/her advertisement details;
3. UPDATE page, which collects data form the profile form and enters it in the MySQL database, and
4. PREVIEW page, where customer can preview appearance of his/her ad.

I wish to have a hidden field on the login page, or alternatively on the profile page, after the customer is logged in, which should add 2 years to the current date and be entered into MySQL database only once, after the customer’s first login. That date will be the expiry date for the advertisement. It will be entered only once in the database, at the first login.

I have tried, without success, on the PROFILE page:

```
$Expires = $con->prepare('SET expires=DateAd("yyyy",2,Date()) WHERE ad_id = $ad_id AND expires is NULL');
```

And in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Expires" value="<?php echo $Expires?>"/>
```

And on the UPDATE page:

```
$query=$connect->query("UPDATE ads SET expires='$Expires' WHERE ad_id='$ad_id'");
```

Does anyone know solution? I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Given that the expiry date is always two years after the first login, why bother storing it at all?

Comment: Your `DateAdd` function in sql template is misspelled. And you can calculate that date on PHP side using `strtotime` function.